# Adjacent divs showing 1px gap in Safari but no other browsers

Tags: css, html, safari

There is a 1px gap between adjacent divs in Safari but no other browsers including Chrome and Firefox. Have a look: http://www.blakearchive.org/blake/public/exhibits/canterburySpecial.html

The menu div is float left and 34% wide and the gallery div is float right and 66% wide. If I make the gallery div float left, the 1px gap shows up at the far right of the screen. If I fill it in with a border (1px) it looks fine in Safari, but of course it throws the div positions off in other browsers. Is there something unique to Safari that is making this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with how Safari rounds pixels and is a common bug.

For example if you had a 100px wrapper, with 3* 33.33% width divs, Safari would round this to 33% and make each div 33px wide, meaning in total it would be 99px, and you'd notice a 1px gap.

The fixed you tried is often a good solution. If you set box-sizing to border-box, this should stop the div being thrown off position, as border-box includes the border in the size of the div rather than extra.